# Text showing on two lines with span

Tags: html, css, text

Please see below HTML and CSS code.

HTML:

```
<a class="navbar-brand"  href="/index.php"> <img src="/img/logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
<span class="navbar-brand" style="font-family:'Arial';font-size:24pt">WEBSITE NAME</span>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-brand {
width: 88px;
height: 88px; 
}
.navbar-brand img {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
```

The problem I'm having is that the text in the span (WEBSITE NAME) is showing on two lines on the page, like so:

WEBSITE
NAME

[image]

I've played around with CSS all to no avail. What I have found, though is that when the image of logo.png is set to a smaller size, the text will in fact sit on one line, but once the image size is increased it doesn't like it.

Comment: width:auto for span.navbar-brand class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `white-space:nowrap` to the span:

```
span.navbar-brand{
 white-space:nowrap;
 width:auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kk60youo/

Answer (score 0):

on navbar-brand class you specify width is 88px. But on text style you put 24px size with all caps. This not fit on this given space (88px). In that case my suggestion is to make the font size smaller like 14px or so.

Thanks